# How to intercept an image request using cy.intercept

Tags: cypress, browser-cache, cy.intercept

I am trying to set up an intercept for an image, load a page and wait for the request to the image Ultimately I would like to replace the image (just to add context), but for now I would just like to detect the image.

I have read https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept, and I must be missing something.

My test is (based on https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/stubbing-spying__intercept/cypress/e2e/image-spec.cy.js):

```
it('matches the base image', () => {
      cy.intercept(
        'GET',
        'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/ace/standard/480/cpsprodpb/AB35/production/_129792834_gettyimages-1256077146.jpg',
      ).as('image');
      cy.visit('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election/2023/england/results');
      cy.wait('@image');
});
```

The error I get in my test is:

`CypressError: Timed out retrying after 5000ms: 'cy.wait()' timed out waiting '5000ms' for the 1st request to the route: 'image'. No request ever occurred. https://on.cypress.io/wait`

I am using Cypress version 13.5.0.

I hope I have included enough for my query to make sense. Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: In your sample code you have `cy.wait('@image')` outside the test (which gives a different error message). If you move it inside the test, the test passes.

Comment: Yes, I have modified that - it was a error with my copying across.If that works for you could you let me know what version of Cypress you are using? It absolutely refuses to pass for me. Thanks for the comment by the way.

Comment: Yes, so now I just got a fail - same message as you have - so looks like the test is flaky rather than totally failing.

Comment: Cypress v13.5.0

Comment: Ha ha, well at least it has worked for one of us :) Thanks for the info. I'll do some more digging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran the sample code it initially passed, then subsequent runs (test runner open) it failed.

Looking at the devtools Network tab I can see an entry `data:image` that has a note ***served from memory cache***. I've no idea if this is loading the image, but caching requests can cause `cy.intercept()` to fail.

#### Clearing the browser cache

This answer by @Fody has a way to clear the browser cache using chrome devtools protocol, which is available as a call to `Cypress.automation()`:

[How to clear browser cache within a Cypress test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940944/how-to-clear-browser-cache-within-a-cypress-test)

```js
const registerCypressGrep = require('@cypress/grep')
registerCypressGrep()

it('matches the base image', () => {

  cy.wrap(Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
    command: 'Network.clearBrowserCache',
  }))

  cy.intercept(
    'GET',
    'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/ace/standard/480/cpsprodpb/AB35/production/_129792834_gettyimages-1256077146.jpg'
  ).as('image')
  cy.visit('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election/2023/england/results');
  cy.wait('@image')
})
```

I also set `chromeWebSecurity: false` in config and specified the chrome browser.

#### Burn testing

Since the test was a little flaky, I decided to burn-test with `@cypress/grep`

This is the script in package.json

```js
"scripts": {
  "burn": "npx cypress run --spec=cypress/e2e/bbc.cy.js --env burn=10 --browser chrome"
}
```

This is the burn-test terminal result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for that. That's really good info and a great answer, thanks again.